# Intellisense in private modules

Tags: vba, intellisense

Assume I have a module named `Module1` with the following code:

```
Private Sub MyPrivateSub()
    'do something
End Sub

Public Sub MyPublicSub()
    'do something
End Sub

Public Sub test()

End Sub
```

If I place the cursor inside `Test()` and start typing "MyPrivateSub" or "MyPublicSub", I don't get any intellisense.  I can type "Module1." (or "Me." if `Module1` were a class module) to get an intellisense menu, but this only contains the public method `MyPublicSub`, as shown here:

[image]

Is there some way to get an intellisense menu for all members, public and private?  I'm working on a project with modules that have many methods, and going up and down continually to copy/paste member names is time consuming.

Comment: me how is correct, however if you are starting from fresh there might have an alternative

Comment: let me ask you one question @roryap, what would you do with `Module1.MyPrivateSub()` or what functionality do you get out of `Module1.MyPublicSub()`? Why do you need reference to it in the first place?

Comment: @mehow -- I'm calling the private method internally within the module, and I'm calling the public method externally from other modules.  The methods contain code that is needed in multiple places (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: @Alex -- can you please elaborate?

Comment: @roryap how are you calling it? What does DRY have to do with all this I have no idea ;) seems like you haven't presented the real-life problem and your SSCCE doesnt really express what you are after

Comment: @mehow -- My post explains how I'm calling it.  Either `Module1.MyPrivateSub` or just `MyPrivateSub`.  I guess I don't understand your question.

Comment: it's rather long, I will write in answer section to explain.  Ignore it if it doesn't fit your scenario.

Comment: @mehow -- I haven't presented a real-life problem because it would be superfluous and largely irrelevant.  My question is simple enough; why try to make it more complicated?  As for DRY: imagine `MyPrivateSub` encapsulates some business logic that I don't want to repeat over and over again in other places --  maybe it reads from a config file and transforms some data.  Who really cares what it does?  Why is that relevant?

Comment: @mehow -- Please just step back and look at my question for what it is, and trust that I have enough experience to understand the unspoken aphorisms and best practices.  I don't need to be schooled on programming practices; please just answer the question or don't answer it, but stop trying to lead it in a different direction.  In my mind, it's a pretty clear question that either has an answer, or it doesn't.

Comment: @mehow trying to follow on your points as you're the vba wizard.  What is DRY?

Comment: @Alex -- follow the link I posted to DRY in wikipedia.

Comment: @roryap it does matter :) everything you do in programming matters. When you decide to make your sub/function/variable `private` you do that for a reason and what you seem to be lacking is the ability to understand why you're making it private. The scope of a member is dictated by its access level and in VBE anything that is private does not get intelli-sense.

Comment: @mehow -- This is what is frustrating about Stack Overflow.  You can never seem to ask a question without attracting some expert programmers who bandy about their experience and muddy your question with pedantry.  "What [I] seem to be lacking is the ability to understand why [I'm] making it private" -- I understand perfectly well why I'm making it private, but that's *not relevant* vis-a-vis this question.  Why does that matter?  But since you insist -- I'm making it private to hide the details from other modules .  Why make anything private? (That's a rhetorical question).

Comment: @roryap Ok, great. Please don't get so upset I am here to help you and just want to clarify a few details before giving an answer. See, I as answerer sometimes also [***have doubts whether to answer or not***](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261402/am-i-overkilling-questions-with-solutions-that-are-too-complex-for-the-op-to-und). I hope you are satisfied with the answer though :)

Comment: @mehow -- The reason I'm frustrated is that, like I said, I can never seem to ask a simple question without it snowballing into something else in the comments.  To me, "Is there some way to get an intellisense menu for all members, public and private?" is a pretty straightforward question.  Thank you for your answer; the "short answer" is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

hit a combination of

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>

and start typing the sub name like shown here

[image]

## Long answer

Everything you do in programming matters. When you decide to make your sub/function/variable private you do that for a reason and you need to understand how this will affect the access level and "scope".

The scope of a member is dictated by its access level and in VBE anything that is private and qualified with it's parent member does not get intelli-sense. Simply, because you can't (*are not supposed to be able to access it*) from the *outside*.

Because your `MyPrivateSub` access level is `Private` you can't access it with intelli-sense through qualifying the module with `Module1.`.

Comment: What's confusing is that `Module1.MyPrivateSub` is allowed by VBA inside `Module1` yet does not show in the list, as if Intellisense doesn't have any idea what is the current module name

Comment: @z̫͋ sorry, what is confusing about it? Is it the access level of `Private`? If something is `private` in VBA it is accessible from the same module but qualifying it with `Module1.` doesn't allow you call its private methods and it does not matter where you call it from.

Comment: Yes it does, if called from the same module

Comment: @z̫͋ I am sorry I am quite confused now. `ctrl+space` allow you to call all members disregard of their access level. When you qualify the private `MyPrivateSub` via `Module1.` it's like trying to access it globally - dot syntax. Since you have made it private it makes perfect sense to me **NOT** to allow the private members in the intelli-sense.

Comment: I agree that the module prefix for function calls should be restricted to public calls, but since VBA allows private calls (with the module prefix) if the function is in the same module, why not show it in the list?

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting from fresh, you can do the following:
for all your private sub function, name them into a standard format but as public function at the moment, for e.g.:

Public sub iamprivate_calDate ()
Public sub iamprivate_getsetfunction()
...

after you're completed with your macros, simply find and replace all your "Public sub iamprivate" into "Private sub " in your editor.

Comment: No offence but I think this is an overkill. All you need to do is to change `Private` to `Public` -> write your code -> then swap it back to `Private`.

Comment: @mehow I thought this would do better if there are tons of functions, but I guess you're right~